# Assigning hash inside each does not work

Tags: ruby, local-variables

This:

```
(0..8).each do |n|
  "a_#{n}" = {}
end
```

gives me an error "syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end". I wanted to create `a_0 = {}`, `a_1 = {}`, `a_2 = {}` etc.

Comment: Why don't you use a hash or an array?

Comment: Falsetru I am not sure what you mean, I do have to use n and I need to go through each, ruby thinks "a_#{n}" is a string and I want to use that as a variable. Any help, thanks !

Comment: Of course Ruby thinks it's a string: because it _is_ a string!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Ok rephrased, my question is how do i create a_0 = {}, a_1 = {}, a_2 = {} etc. until a_n

Comment: Your design is wrong.. Think on it.

Comment: @Arup Rakshit How would you design it, the goal is simple and clear.

Comment: I agree with @Arup, there's no need to create variable names on the fly. This is what data structures and/or objects are for.

Comment: The goal is not simple not clear. The goal isn't even stated. You simply posted a piece of not-working code and said "it doesn't work". You don't mention what the goal is. Without knowing what the goal is, there is no way to help you. From the looks of it, you lack a basic understanding of data structures and programming in general, but without knowing your specific goals, there is not much more to say than "use an `Array`".

Answer (score 2):

I think you want an array of hashes.

```
a = []
(0..8).each do |n|
  a[n] = {}
end
```

Result:

```
a #=> [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]

a[0] #=> {}
a[1] #=> {}
...etc...
```

although depending on what you need to do next, this type of initialization may not be necessary.

Comment: `a = Array.new(9){{}}` would be much better.

Comment: @mark I want to achieve a_0 = {}, a_1 = {} ..etc not like the result above.

Comment: @sawa, I agree, but I was trying to minimally change the OP's code as I assumed this was a learning experience.

Comment: @KB_enreach Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Mark I want to achieve the following
**What I have:**
`{"kv1001"=>{"impressions"=>{"b"=>0.2452, "a"=>0.707},"visitors"=>{"b"=>0.2294,"a"=>0.711},"ctr"=>{"b"=>0.0038793, "a"=>0.0038},"inScreen"=>{"b"=>3.9503587, "a"=>5.0314902580305425}}`
**MY GOAL**
`{"segment"=>"kv1001=a", "impressions"=>"0.757", "visitors"=>"0.71031","in_screen_time"=>"5.0314","ctr"=>"0.0038"},{"segment"=>"kv1001=b", "impressions"=>"0.234", "visitors"=>"0.2889694","in_screen_time"=>"3.9507","ctr"=>"0.00387"}`

If you could help, I'd be the happies user of stackoverflow today :)

Comment: @KB_enreach Ah, now *that* is a completely different question. And as such, I recommend that you ask a new question, providing the above information plus some context (e.g. what rules determine how the input gets to be the output). You'll get lots of help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have already posted a new question.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186259/constructing-a-new-hash-from-the-given-vlaues)

Answer (score 1):

```
binding.instance_eval do (0..8).each do |i|
  local_variable_set("a_#{i}", {})
  ...
end end
```

Comment: Yes I was seeing it since last 10 minutes [`local_variable_set `](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set). But it is not good for this case. As, to access those local variables, you need to use the `Binding` object. This is creating local variables inside the scope of the binding object. On the top level if you want to access it, you will get error. If you want to access the value, you need to use the method [`local_variable_get`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get).

Comment: Thank you, Is there though any way to achieve this without using local_variable_set gem ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I didn't do it in top level. It is inside the scope of binding.

Comment: @user3616241 Yes. There is no local_variable_set gem.

Comment: I know.. I am just trying to tell, if you want to get the value, you have to have the binding object with you. But you could do `b = binding`. Then `b.local_variable_set("a_#{i}", {})`. You need `b`, as to get the value back .

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes. The whole attempt is bad in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Without bad magic, you won't get the functionality you want (there are ways to do that but they are bad and hacky). Use a hash or array instead.

Comment: I just don't get the sentence 'use a hash or array' am i not using a hash there already ?

Comment: This means that you should use a hash or an array on the **left** side of your assignment.

Comment: @KB_enreach: Instead of using multiple variables `a_0`, `a_1`, … just use on array or hash `a` and use it like: `a[n] = {}`.